# Ruby / Ruby on Rails, continuous loop polling database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a few external databases and I want to get pretty close to realtime data transfer. I will be just doing a simple query e.g

```
select count(total) from invoices where date = 'today'; // pseudo code
```

So I want to find a way to continuously call a database query that can run for days / months on end without problem, and if there is a problem self heal / restart

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you mind clarifying your request a little? Is the external database not on RoR? Can you just run a SQL query on that external DB (in Ruby), serve up JSON and then consume it in a RoR app? Have you looked at something like [these](http://tobinharris.com/past/2009/3/9/6-ways-to-run-background-jobs-in-rubyonrails/) or just using cron to just run your queries on the server as a background process?

Comment: Don't use a database, use a message queue like RabbitMQ. It's made for this purpose, is hugely scalable, extremely fast, and nicely self-healing if you write your nodes correctly. Constantly polling a database is bad for the DB because it loads it down unnecessarily, along with adding a load to the machine doing the polling.

Comment: It's polling an external PostgreSQL.. I don't have a choice but to poll this with a query as I don't control the db design..